# How to remove \n and \t from a list in python?

Tags: python, lambda, web-scraping

I have been trying to remove \n and \t from 2 lists in python but have been unable to do so. Below is my code:

```
A=[]
B=[]
C=[]
D=[]
.................
.................

df=pd.DataFrame(A,columns=['Rank'])
df['Company Name']=B
C=list(filter(lambda x: x != '\n', C))
C=list(filter(lambda x: x != '\t', C))
df['Type of organization']=C
D=list(filter(lambda x: x != '\n', D))
D=list(filter(lambda x: x != '\t', D))
df['Industry']=D


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('compdata.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='report')
writer.save()
```

Kindly help me out as I have tried lambda as well but to no avail. Every time I export the data frame to Excel, it gives me a lot of spaces in those 2 columns.

Below is how C and D looks like:

```
  Rank                 Company Name  \
0   1.            Google (Alphabet)   
1   2.                       ACUITY   
2   3.  The Boston Consulting Group   
3   4.         Wegmans Food Markets   

                                Type of organization  \
0  \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t...   
1  \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t...   
2  \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t...   
3  \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t...   

                                            Industry  
0  \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t...  
1  \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t...  
2  \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t...  
3  \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t...
```

In actuality, Type of organization should have either "Public" or "Private". It's just that the list has a lot of \n and \t before either of the aforementioned choices.

Comment: show your data - what do you have in `C` and `D` ? And what means `'a lot of spaces'` ? Maybe you have empty cells or empty strings in cells, not `'\t'` or `'\n'`.

Comment: Pls, show us example of your `C` list. If it is a list of strings, then your solution should work.

Comment: you can probably avoid having them in the first place by `strip()`ing your data before you import it. This might be a XY problem.

Comment: This work
    
    list = ['a\n', 'b\t']
    new_list = [item.strip()for item in list]

    new_list = ['a', 'b']

Comment: >>> C
['\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPublic', '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPrivate', '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPrivate', '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPrivate']

Comment: >>> D
['\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAdvertising & Marketing', '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tFinancial Services & Insurance', '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tProfessional Services', '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRetail']

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', '\n', 'c', '\t', 'd']

my_list = [item for item in my_list if item not in ['\n', '\t']]
```

Using [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
my_list = filter(lambda item: item not in ['\n', '\t'], my_list)
```

**Edit:**

For the example of inputs added to the question, you can remove `\t` and `\n` like this:

```
c = [''.join(item.split()) for item in c]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> c = ['\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t‌​\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPu‌​blic', '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\‌​t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPri‌​vate', '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\‌​t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPri‌​vate', '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\‌​t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPri‌​vate']
>>>
>>> [''.join(item.split()) for item in c]
['??Pu??blic', '\\??tPri??vate', '\\??tPri??vate', '\\??tPri??vate']
```

Comment: Your solution is great. But it does exactly the same what OP code does. I think `C` list looks different.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych, You're right. OP needs to add the content of `C` list

Comment: @ettanany: When I apply this code, following appears in list:

<filter object at 0x04DE46F0> in C
<filter object at 0x050AC270> in D

Comment: @TusharAgarwal Please take a look at the edited answer.

Comment: @TusharAgarwal You're welcome! Don't forget to accept my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
C = [ x.replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '') for x in C ]
```

same for `D`